# Can I search for black pixels in a photo and find out where they are in the photo using python?

Tags: python, color-detection

I want to search for black pixels in a screenshot I took using pyautogui and I want to find the x and y location of those pixels using python so that I can move the mouse to the black pixels locations using pynput. I tried using imageio but I could not find a command that would do what I want. I asked this a few hours Ago but it was closed so I made the necessary edits to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way in Python/OpenCV/Numpy using np.argwhere on a thresholded image that isolates the black spots.

- Read the input
- Threshold using inRange on black and invert
- Use np.argwhere to located the coordinates of the black pixels in the mask
- Print the results

Input (4 black clusters near the 4 corners):

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read input
img = cv2.imread("lena_black_spots.png")

low = (0,0,0)
high = (0,0,0)

mask = cv2.inRange(img, low, high)
mask = 255 - mask

# find black coordinates
coords = np.argwhere(mask==0)
for p in coords:
    pt = (p[0],p[1])
    print (pt)

# save output
cv2.imwrite('lena_black_spots_mask.png', mask)

cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.imshow('mask', mask)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Mask:

[image]

Coordinates:

```
(18, 218)
(18, 219)
(19, 218)
(19, 219)
(20, 218)
(20, 219)
(38, 21)
(38, 22)
(39, 21)
(39, 22)
(173, 244)
(173, 245)
(174, 244)
(174, 245)
(194, 23)
(194, 24)
(195, 23)
(195, 24)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend looking into the [ImageMagick](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ImageMagick) library. That's the go-to library for working with images in Python.